# Which data structure should I use to store large 10,000 data set and do fastest search ,and take least memory?

Tags: binary-search-tree, b-tree, quadtree, spatial-query, r-tree

*Suppose I have 10,000 circle(x,y,r) values , and i want to find a point (p1,p2) lies in which circle , to get fastest response for this query what data structure should i use to store those 10,000 circle data.
It is a static data ,means one time construct ,

But most frequent operation will be search query. and It will Not be a range based search or not nearest neighbor search

How about B-tree ,B+ tree or R-tree or Quadtree or linear Interpolation search or any  bitmap kind , solution should take least memory while little extra time trade off is okay.*

Comment: First you say "_to get fastest response_" but then later you say "_solution should take least memory while little extra time trade off is okay_". Which are you aiming for, lowest time or lowest memory?

Comment: Aiming for lowest memory than lowest time , :-)

Comment: I feel Quadtree takes a lot of memory and  many recursive calls to construct  it  compared to R-tree. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Linear array uses least memory. QuadTree will be a bit tricky with the radius, but if you have a rather even data distribution, it will do pretty good. You never know before you benchmark what works for your data!

Comment: I'd go with the linear array, but sorted  x+r. At just 10k points, this can be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three choices:

- Use a bounding volume hierarchy (BVH); in this case i think 2D sphere tree (circle tree) will be the way to go; So you construct a tree which each node is circle. Each node can contain children circles. Your input circles will be on leafs. This way point search will be logN in time but structure will be NlogN in space. But, generally BVH may be hard to construct.
- Use a tree based N-ary space partitioning (binary space partitioning, qudtree, 2D kd-tree); This time you partition space, and each space may contain some spheres. These algorithms will have the same complexity as BVH, but most likely will be less efficient than BVH - I suspect lesser thight fitting for circles. But, some space partitionings (eg quadtree) can be easier to construct.
- Use spatial hashing. That is space will be partitioned into cubes (buckets) of exact size and theses cubes hashed. Basically, you may think about it as a uniform grid of pixels (but smartly stored), when each pixel have list of contained circles. This in theory gives O(1) for search. But space may be more complicated to predict. It is in theory O(N) but may be bigger than BVH due to const factor - and most likely depends on distribution of circle's area and position (eg. number of pixels which have circles).